# Variable from javascript wont get passed on to the form

Tags: javascript, html, django

The variable ocode does not get passed to the def resetusername.
document.getElementById("ocode").value gets the value from storageName and I verified it by using 'alert' function.
Can anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong.Thank you

```
 function mySubmit() {

         document.getElementById("ocode").value = 
         localStorage.getItem("storageName");
         alert(document.getElementById("ocode").value);
         document.getElementById("myform").action = "/postresetusername/";

  }


 <form  method="post"  id="myform" onsubmit="mySubmit()">
 {% csrf_token %}
      <div class = "login-box">
      <h1>Reset Username</h1>

      <div class = "textbox" style="float:left">
          <input type = "email"     placeholder="Previous Email"  name = "email" id="email">
      </div>


     <input type='hidden' id= "ocode" name='id' value="">






 def postresetusername(request):
    email = request.POST.get('email')
    ocode = request.POST.get('ocode')
    authe.verify_password_reset_code(ocode, "new_pwd")
          return render(request, "signIn2.html", {"messg": "Password reset"})
 return render(request, "signIn2.html", {"messg": "Cant reset"})
```

Answer (score 1):

Forms inputs use the name and you are using the id.

```
<input type='hidden' id= "ocode" name='id' value="">
                                 ^^^^^^^^^
```

and the backend is using

```
ocode = request.POST.get('ocode')
                          ^^^^^
```